# Delete ALL non unique elements (including atoms, pairs, lists) from list Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, unique

I'm trying to write a Scheme function that will return the unique elements found in the input list. This function should work with atoms, pairs and lists. I mean if the input list looks like '(1 1 2 (2 . 2) (2 . 2) (4 3) (4 3) 3 5 2 4) the function should return (5).

Here is my current code:

```
(define (delduplicates L)
   (cond ((null? L) '())
           ((list? (member (car L) (cdr L)))
            (delduplicates(cdr L)))
            (#T (cons (car L) (delduplicates (cdr L))))))
(delduplicates '(1 1 2 3 3 4 4 5)) > (1 2 3 4 5)
```

The problem with this is that it only removes duplicates.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you ask a specific question about this? Right now it seems like you're expecting us to write this for you, which we don't do here. Please read the following: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 0):

I've done this so far:

```
(define (delduplicates L)
(cond ((null? L) '())
((list? (member (car L) (cdr L)))(delduplicates(cdr L)))
(#T (cons (car L) (delduplicates (cdr L))))))
(delduplicates '(1 1 2 3 3 4 4 5))
> (1 2 3 4 5)
```

As u can see, it only removes duplicates. I'm new to this type of programming and my imperative mindset prevents any attempts to think in a declarative way.